# Microsoft.Bcl.Async doesn't work

Tags: .net, async-await, portable-class-library, base-class-library

I try to use Async with Portable Class Library. I use Profile 104, which includes:

- .NET 4.5
- Silverlight 4
- WP 7.5
- WinRT

Installation works and I can use `System.Threading.Tasks` but I can't compile because I have this error:

> Cannot await `System.Threading.Task<System.Net.HttpWebResponse>`

On the line with `await` in this sample:

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync(string urlToCall)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToCall);
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Why?

**Update**

My profile 104 is update with monodroid and monotouch
I use NuGet to install Microsoft.Bcl.Async v 1.0.16
If I add AsyncBridge.Portable v 0.2.0 I have no warning of Visual Studio, but it doesn't compile.
There are conflicts between this 2 libraries in System.Attributes

How make working this libraries together ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me with that setting (after I replaced `HttpMethod.Get` with `"GET"`).

Comment: What .NET Framework are you targeting when you compile?

Comment: I use this library with WPF project. I found sample with same profile and it compile on my visual studio, but it use AsyncBridge.Portable and Microsoft.Bcl.Async. Have you use it ?

Comment: Are there any other errors or warnings in the project output when you compile?

Answer (score 2):

I used Bcl.async and AsyncBridge.Portable  from Nuget and I had errors.

If I use Bclasync from Nuget with AsyncBridge.Portable created by Daniel Plaisted it's ok.

I'm interested to know what is Daniel doing to make working this lib ?

Thanks,

Comment: Basically, I used AsyncBridge to create a MonoAndroid implementation of the same surface area that is in Microsoft.Bcl.Async.  This involved type-forwarding some types to the Mono equivalents, and implementing others based on the AsyncBridge code.  You have the source code for my version, right?

Comment: Yes I have Async.Facade but I don't understand how make PCL dll with this kind of project. I would like to use type forwarding to have System.Data.IDbConnection in PCL library. At runtime I want to inject System.Data.SQLite or Mono.Data.SQLite. Do you think it's possible ?

Comment: I'd suggest asking a separate question about System.Data.IDbConnection, that doesn't seem to be directly related to your issues with Bcl.Async.